# Bluetooth not working since upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, bluetooth, 22.04

bluetooth has not been doing ok since the update. I have to turn it off and on a bunch of times, most of the times it wont detect my speaker and I can only connect through a script that sends the specific mac address to connect to, which is very tedious for new devices.

This is my sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth output:

```
[    5.380362] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.380559] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.380561] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.380565] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.380567] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.380584] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.461604] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[    5.463593] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    5.463594] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[    5.500380] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[    5.500981] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 27814
[    5.758599] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x09a98a6b
[    7.186485] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.186489] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.186493] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   41.143590] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   41.143599] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   41.143602] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   43.168023] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[   45.184014] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[ 8074.522476] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[ 8076.534465] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
```

Further System information:
Hardware model Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C37, Processor AMD® Ryzen 5 3600 6-core processor × 12, Graphics AMD® Radeon rx vega, OS Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64 bit, GNOME 42.0, Windowing System Wayland.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Can you add information about your computer? Including things such as brand, model, architecture, and motherboard can help us give a better answer. You don't have to include all of it.

Comment: Hey Jeff, for sure. I just edited the original post at the bottom with some info. Please let me know if there is something specific I should add. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding the info.

See this guide (it may or may not be helpful) https://superuser.com/questions/1289782/bluetooth-stopped-working-correctly-after-possible-update

I am not the best person to answer this, but I try to help where I may.

Comment: I had the same issue and did [this workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/738371/117844), maybe it can help you?

Comment: Thanks for the input deFreitas. I finally fixed the issue (sort of) by using a script that disconnected and reconnected my usb devices (bluetooth usb included) and retries the connection to the speaker and got it working as a work around. But bluetooth is not great in general in linux,